# Is there an automatic way to make a diagram of library dependecies?

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to create a dependencie graph in netbean so I want to know if there is some tool that do it or help.

Comment: The tool you're using to manage your dependencies seems pertinent, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the dependency graph in NetBeans? When you open a pom.xml you have above the document a "Graph" button which shows you exactly what you are looking for.

If you want to implement such a graph on you own and need some help, you can have a look at the implementation: https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans/tree/master/java/java.graph/src/org/netbeans/modules/java/graph